# How to deploy web application in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, publish

I created one **ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application** and here i selected **Web Api** template.
All things are working fine then i want to publish this application to IIS server7.5.
Here I select the **Web Deploy Package** method for publish. Here i got one **zip** file.
After that i deploy it to my IIS Server and Run this application from IIS server it's display my files only not run my pages.

I don't know why it's not show my application.

I done the following steps in Visual Studio 2012.

**Right click on project name** in the solution explorer and **select publish**.

Then give the **profile name** and select the **Web Deploy Package** for in **Publish Method** here i select the path for publish application and click **Publish** Button.
Then i got one zip file.

I done the following steps in IIS Manger.

Right click on the **Default web site** in here select Deploy ==> import Application then select my created **zip** file and finally my application added under the **Default web site** and i select my application, Right click on that and select **Manage Application** ==> **Browse**
and its display my files only not display my pages.

like

[To Parent Directory]
                                                                                                          12/14/2013  4:46 PM         bin

12/14/2013  4:46 PM         Content

11/15/2013  3:24 PM        32038 favicon.ico

11/15/2013  3:24 PM          109 Global.asax

12/14/2013  4:46 PM         Images

11/15/2013  3:25 PM         2045 packages.config

12/14/2013  4:46 PM         Scripts

12/14/2013  4:46 PM         Views

12/14/2013  4:45 PM         6379 Web.config**

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go into IIS, click on your website in the tree menu and then look for an icon called 'Directory Browsing'. Click on this and make sure it is disabled.

Comment: i disabled the Directory Browsing, after that IIS Server throw Config Error Unrecognized attribute 'allowOverride'

Comment: Do you have the right version of .net and mvc installed on your server?

Comment: I have .Net framework 4.5 and use MVC 4 in my visual studio.....